# Real varieties with enough algebraic loops

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, real-algebraic-geometry, loop-spaces, loop-groups

Let $(X,\sigma)$ be a complex variety with complex conjugation (equivalently, an algebraic variety over $\mathbb R$).
We use the notations $X(\mathbb R):=X^\sigma$ for the set of fixed points of $X$ under $\sigma$. Equivalently, this is the set of real points of the algebraic variety $X$.

Here's a property which I believe compact semisimple real algebraic groups to have (but not $S^1$!):

> Any algebraic map from $S^1:=(\mathbb C^\times,z\mapsto \bar z^{-1})$ to $(X,\sigma)$ induces a $\mathit C^\infty$ map from $S^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $X(\mathbb{R})$. 
>   Let us say that $X$ *has enough algebraic loops* if these algebraically induced are dense in the space of all
>   $\mathit C^\infty$ maps from $S^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $X(\mathbb{R})$, equipped with the $C^\infty$ topology.

• Is it true that $(G,\sigma)$ has enough algebraic loops? Here, $G$ is a complex semisimple algebraic group and $\sigma$ its Cartan involution (so that $G^\sigma$ is the compact form of $G$)

• Note that the spheres $S^n$ (see David's comment for their precise definition) seem to have enough algebraic loops iff $n\not = 1$. Indeed, this would follow from the previous statement given that they are homogeneous spaces. Is this indeed true?

• Is there a reasonably large class of real algebraic varieties for which one can prove that they have enough algebraic loops?

Comment: I'm confused when you say "Let $(X,\sigma)$ be a complex variety with complex conjugation (equivalently, a variety over $\mathbb{R})$". The sphere $S^n$ is a real variety but it is *not* almost-complex, unless $n=2$ or $n=6$. 
I'm missing something about this "equivalently"?

Comment: The complex variety in question is $\{ (z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_n) : z_0^2+z_1^2+\cdots + z_n^2=1 \}$, the involution $\sigma$ is $(z_0, z_1, \ldots, z_n) \mapsto (\overline{z}_0, \overline{z}_1, \ldots, \overline{z}_n)$.

Comment: Have you looked at "Quillen's theorem on buildings and the loops on a symmetric space" by Steve Mitchell?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: you are interested in density, not in approximation of (truncated) homotopy types by spaces of algebraic maps?  Either way, I suggest you take a look at the articles of Graeme Segal, et al., on approximating loop groups and spaces of continuous maps to homogeneous varieties by algebraic maps.  This is mostly in the complex setting, rather than the real setting . . .

Comment: Just to check, $S^1$ in this context means $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1 \}$, right? And your maps must be given by polynomials in $x$ and $y$, not just rational functions whose poles are disjoint from the real locus. For example, $(x,y) \mapsto 1/(2-x^2-y^2)$ is not okay, right?

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I expect that Henriques means that $\mathbf{S}^1$ is $\{z\in \mathbb{C}^\times | z\overline{z} = 1\}$, i.e., the fixed locus under the involution $\tau$, $z\mapsto \overline{z}^{-1}$.  The maps from $\mathbb{C}^\times$ to $(X,\sigma)$ that Henriques wants are those (complex) polynomial maps $f(z)$ such that $\sigma\circ f$ equals $f\circ \tau$.

Comment: @Jason: I am aware of the papers that prove that the inclusion of algebraic loop groups into smooth loop groups are homotopy equivalences. This is done by computing cohomology on both sides (by different methods) and checking that the induced map is an isomorphism. Density is a much stronger requirement, and I'm wondering if it also holds. @ David and Jason: you are both right! I tried to edit my question to make it less confusing. I hope that I didn't make things any worse (feel free to edit).

Comment: I edited; see if it is better or worse.

Comment: @AndréHenriques:  Frankly I don't see how to get density for, say, the compact-open topology.  However, for every finite subset of $\mathbf{S}^1$ (unfortunately not all compact subsets), perhaps we can prove existence of a (real) algebraic morphism with specified values on that finite set.  This is related to "strong approximation" of adelic points by integral points (for the "integer ring" $\mathbb{R}[z,z^{-1}]$).  Much is known about strong approximation for algebraic groups.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously, if $X$ is complete, you can just speak about maps $\mathbb{P}^1\to X$, or you can also replace $\mathbb{P}^1$ with the "standard" circle (conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$). This approximation problem used to be popular, see e.g. the survey

> MR2882786 
>   Bochnak, Jacek; Kucharz, Wojciech
>   *Algebraic approximation of smooth maps*.
>   Univ. Iagel. Acta Math. No. 48 (2010), 9–40.

Right away, in an earlier paper

> MR0873026
>   Bochnak, J.; Kucharz, Wojciech
>   *Algebraic approximation of mappings into spheres.* 
>   Michigan Math. J. 34 (1987), no. 1, 119–125

they give an affirmative answer to your question (among others) for $X=S^n$ with $n=1,2,4$. (Accidentally, the survey claims that their conjecture is still open for other values of $n$. Though, the conjecture is more general that your question about $S^1$.)

Comment: The second paper cited is studying "entire rational maps" not polynomial maps. In the context of our problem, write $S^1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1 \}$. The components of their maps $S^1 \to Y$ will be rational functions $f(x,y)/g(x,y)$ so that $g$ is nowhere vanishing on $S^1$. Andre wants honest polynomials.

Comment: The same comment applies to the first paper.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I do not believe that Henriques wants "honest polynomials".  I believe he wants morphisms, $f:\mathbb{C}^\times \to X$ such that $\sigma \circ f$ equals $f\circ \tau$, where $\tau(z) = \overline{z}^{-1}$.  So $f$, considered as a rational map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to some completion of $X$, is allowed to have arbitrary poles at the (conjugate) pair $\{0,\infty\}$.  Of course, for $X$ that are already complete, as in Degtyarev's answer, there are no poles at all (because $X$ is complete).  That is why these "entire rational maps" are "entire".

Comment: @JasonStarr That's the same thing! I thought that writing the circle as $x^2+y^2=1$ was more intuitive. You are saying that the coordinates of $f$ should be of the form $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} f_k z^k$ with $f_k = \overline{f}_{-k}$, yes? That ring is generated by $x:=(z+z^{-1})/2$ and $y := (z-z^{-1})/(2i)$, subject to $x^2+y^2=1$. This is the same as whether to write Fourier series in terms of $e^{i \theta}$ or in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: If you look at the linked papers, they are looking at rational maps $\mathbb{CP}^1 \to X$, obeying $\sigma \circ f = f \circ \tau$ condition, and with no poles on the unit circle. My point is that I think Andre wants poles to be at $\{ 0, \infty \}$, not just to be off the real points.

Comment: What is a pole? We are speaking about morphisms of algebraic (or analytic) varieties; if the target is complete (and the source is a curve), there's no such thing as a pole.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer:  (1) Maybe it is the same thing.  I talk with people who work on open GW theory, where the pair $(X,\sigma)$ need not be a variety.  Then, 
"$f$ J-holomorphic satisfying $\sigma\circ f = f\circ \tau$" is preferrable to "real polynomial coordinates on the nontrivial real conic".  When $X$ is complete, if we do not specify a "hyperplane at infinity", I just do not understand what you mean by "poles".  For an affine variety, such as a semisimple group, certainly "poles" make sense.  But, for complete $X$, I don't get it.

Comment: For some reason, I seem to be confusing some very intelligent people. I believe (but wanted to confirm) that Andre's $S^1$ is the compact real form of $\mathbb{G}_m$. This is an affine variety. The coordinate ring can be described either as $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$ or as the subring of $\mathbb{C}[z, z^{-1}]$ invariant under the $\mathbb{C}$-antilinear involution sending $z$ to $z^{-1}$. I am assuming this because Andre denoted the variety as $(\mathbb{C}^{\times}, \sigma)$, which I presumed indicated that the morphism had to be defined on all of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: I agree that this distinction would not be interesting if $X$ were proper, but Andre's proposed examples are algebraic groups whose $\mathbb{R}$-points are compact, and hence affine varieties. For example, Andre writes that an arbitrary map $S^1 \to S^1$ cannot be approximated by algebraic maps. This is true with my interpretation (the only algebraic maps are $z \mapsto z^n$ for $n$ an integer) but it is false if we allow maps with other complex poles.

Comment: To spell out what I mean above, let $f: S^1 \to S^1$ be smooth. Replacing $f$ by $f z^{-n}$ for some $n$, we may assume that $f$ has winding number $0$, hence it has a smooth square root $g$. Let $g_1 : S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial in $z$ and $z^{-1}$ approximating $g$ within $\epsilon$; it exists by Runge's theorem. Then $h(z) := g_1(z)/\overline{g}_1(z^{-1})$ (where the bar means to take complex conjugate of the coefficients) is a rational function taking $S^1 \to S^1$. For $|z|=1$, we have $g(z) \approx g_1(z)$ and $|g(z)|=1$ so $h(z) \approx g(z)/\overline{g(z)} = g(z)^2 = f(z)$.

Comment: Here is the way I see this. Functions of one variable have no poles; "poles" are merely pull-backs of a divisor which, for some reason, was distinguished and called infinity (and thus the problem was artificially complexified). So, it looks natural to handle the compact problem first (which, in our case, already appears quite difficult), and then try to through in the extra divisor.

Comment: Let me confirm: David Speyer is right. I care about morphisms defined on all of $\mathbb C^\times$. So the only poles should be at $0$ and at $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of a possible proof $L^{\infty}$ (uniform convergence) approximation of continuous maps to $S^3 = SU(2)$. (Actually, I need my maps to be a little better than continuous, because I need them not to be space filling curves.) As Andre observes, this also implies the result for $S^2$.

I suspect that  someone
with a stronger background in topology could deal with the space
filling curves. I can't decide whether or not I think we should be able to push $L^{\infty}$ to $C^{\infty}$.

We will describe $S^3$ as $\{ (w,x,y,z) : w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 \}$. We'll also think of this as the unit quaternions, writing $w+xi+yj+zk$. Stripped of the sophisticated language, the question is the following: We have a smooth map $\gamma: S^1 \to S^3$. Write $\gamma(\theta) = (w(\theta), x(\theta), y(\theta), z(\theta))$. Can we approximate $\gamma$ by maps $\gamma_1(\theta) = (w_1(\theta), x_1(\theta), y_1(\theta), z_1(\theta))$ where $w_1$, $x_1$, $y_1$ and $z_1$ are given by Fourier series of finite length, and the identity
$$w_1^2 + x_1^2 + y_1^2 + z_1^2 = 1$$
must hold identically.

Since $\gamma$ is not a space filling curve, it misses some point of $S^3$ and we will assume without loss of generality that it misses the quaternion $-1$. We can define the logarithm on $SU(2) \setminus \{ -1 \}$: The logarithm of $w+xi+yj+zk$ is the unique quaternion $pi+qj+rk$ with $\exp(pi+qj+rk) = w+xi+yj+zk$ and $p^2+q^2+r^2 < \pi^2$. For $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and $w+xi+yz+zk \neq -1$, we will define $(w+xi+yz+zk)^a$ to be $\exp(a \log(w+xi+yz+zk))$.

Choose a large integer $n$. For $0 \leq s \leq n-1$, define $a_s : S_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ to be the piecewise linear function which is $1/2$ on $[2 \pi (s-1/2)/n, 2 \pi (s+1/2)/n]$, interpolates linearly between $0$ and $1/2$ on $[2 \pi (s-3/2)/n, 2 \pi (s-1/2)/n]$ and $[2 \pi (s+1/2)/n, 2 \pi (s+3/2)/n]$m and is $0$ on the rest of $S^1$. Define $g_s(\theta) = \gamma(2 \pi s/n)^{a_s(\theta)}$ and define $g(\theta) = \prod_{s=1}^n g_s(\theta)$. As $n \to \infty$, the function $g(\theta)$ uniformly approaches $\gamma(\theta)$. Therefore, it is enough to choose $n$ so that $g$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of $\gamma$, and then approximate each $g_s$ within $\epsilon/(2n)$ by finite Fourier series.

If we wanted to do $C^{\infty}$ approximation rather than $L^{\infty}$, we would of course want the bump functions $a_s$ to be smooth rather than $C^{\infty}$. I expect this isn't hard, but it's not what I want to focus on.

In short, we have reduced to approximating maps of the form $\theta \mapsto q^{a(\theta)}$ where $q$ is a fixed quaternion not equal to $-1$. We may conjugate $q$ to be of the form $a+bi$, so we need to approximate $w(\theta) + x(\theta) i$ by $w_1(\theta) + x_1(\theta) i + y_1(\theta) j + z_1(\theta) k$.

Take $w_1$ and $x_1$ to be finite Fourier series approximations of $w$ and $x$, say within $\epsilon^2/100$. Multiplying by a scalar near $1$, we can further arrange that $w_1^2+x_1^2 \in (1-\epsilon^2/20, 1-\epsilon^2/10)$. Define $u(\theta) = 1-w_1(\theta)^2-x_1(\theta)^2$.

We are now reduced to finding finite Fourier series $y_1(\theta)$ and $z_1(\theta)$ with $y_1^2 + z_1^2 = u$. We no longer need to impose that $y_1$ and $z_1$ are close to $y=z=0$, since this is automatic from the identity $y_1^2 + z_1^2 = u < \epsilon^2/10$.

**Lemma** Let $u: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be a finite Fourier series. Then there are finite Fourier series $y_1$ and $z_1$ with $u=y_1^2+z_1^2$.

**Proof:** We will write $u$ as $\sum u_m q^m$, where $q=e^{i \theta}$. The condition that $u$ is real valued means that $u_{-m}=\overline{u_m}$.

Considering $u(q)$ as a function of a complex variable $q$, we have $u(\overline{q}^{-1}) = \overline{u(q)}$. So, if $\alpha$ is a zero of $u$, so is $\overline{\alpha}^{-1}$.  Also, none of these zeroes can be on the unit circle, since $u$ takes positive values. Therefore we can write
$$u(q) = c \prod (1-q/\alpha_i )(1-q^{-1}/\overline{\alpha_i})$$
for some positive constant $c$ and some list of zeroes $\alpha_i$.

Define $v(q) = \sqrt{c} \prod (1-q/\alpha_i)$; then we have $v(e^{i
\theta}) \overline{v(e^{i \theta})} = u(\theta)$. Take $y_1$ and
$z_1$ to be the real and imaginary parts of $v$. $\square$

Note that this proof gives us no control over the sizes of $y'_1$ and $z'_1$, which is why I can't decide whether we should be able to get convergence in $C^k$ for $k \geq 1$.

---

We can also approximate maps $S^1 \to SO(3)$. Multiplying $\gamma$ by $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta & 0 \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ if necessary, we may assume that $\gamma$ has a square root $\sqrt{\gamma}: S^1 \to SU(2)$. Approximate $\sqrt{\gamma}$ by polynomials and then observe that the squaring map $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ is given by polynomials (I wrote them down [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70154/matrix-expression-for-elements-of-so3/70160#70160).)

---

I think this argument might actually be extendible to all semisimple
compact Lie groups. Here is a crude sketch.

The bump function trick let's us focus on approximating maps $g$ that land
in the exponential of a one dimensional subspace $\mathfrak{s}$ of the Lie algebra.
Let $T$ be the closure of $\exp(\mathfrak{s})$, so $T$ is a torus; let
its Lie algebra be $\mathfrak{t}$. Multiplying by a cocharacter $S^1 \to T$, we may assume that $g: S^1 \to T$ is null homotopic and thus has a logarithm $\log g: S^1 \to \mathfrak{t}$. Let $\mathfrak{r}_1$, $\mathfrak{r}_2$, ...., $\mathfrak{r}_m$ in $\mathfrak{t}$ be the one dimensional subspaces spanned by the simple roots: we can write $\log g$ as a linear combination $\log g = \sum h_i$ of maps $h_i: S^1 \to \mathfrak{r}_i$ and can exponetiate these to maps $\exp(h_i)$ from $S^1$ to one dimensional torii $R_i$. Each $R_i$ sits in an $SU(2)$ or $SO(3)$, so we can approximate $\exp(h_i)$ by the above argument.

Comment: This is a beautiful argument! Your Lemma is particularly pretty, and it's really a shame that it allows for wild oscillations in the directions of the $y_1$ and $z_1$ coordinates. I also completely agree with your last paragraph that claims that this argument easily extends to the case of arbitrary semisimple groups.

Comment: Thanks! The lemma is a modification of a standard proof that a positive polynomial is a sum of squares of two polynomials. Once $u$ is fixed by all the prior choices, there are only finitely many options for $y_1$ and $z_1$, so it makes sense that we can't control their oscillations. But there are so many arbitrary choices before that point, that it certainly seems like we could maneuver to end up with a good $u$ somehow!

Comment: In the proof that $\mathrm{SO}_3$ has enough loops, I do not understand why the continuous $\gamma\colon S^1\rightarrow \mathrm{SO}_3$ has a lift $\sqrt\gamma$ to $\mathrm{SU}_2$. After all, $\mathrm{SO}_3$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf P^3(\mathbf R)$, and $\gamma$ can be homotopically nonzero. Why does it lift to the universal covering?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument that $S^3=SU(2)$ has enough algebraic loops.

First of all, it is enough to consider loops that don't hit the element $-1\in SU(2)$ since they form a dense subset in the space of all loops.

Given a $C^\infty$ loop $\gamma:S^1\to SU(2)$, consider its preimage $\tilde\gamma:S^1\to \mathfrak{su}(2)$ along the exponential map $exp:\mathfrak{su}(2)\to SU(2)$. By standard Fourier analysis, there exist good approximations of $\tilde\gamma$ by trigonometric polynomials.

Now here's an observation:
$$
(\cos(n\theta),0,0)={\textstyle\frac12}
[(\cos(n\theta),\sin(n \theta),0) + (\cos(-n\theta),\sin(-n \theta),0)]
$$
and similarly for $(\sin(n\theta),0,0)$.
Therefore, we may approximate $\tilde \gamma$ by a finite linear combination
$$
\tilde\gamma\,\, \approx\,\, \sum_{i=1}^n f_i
$$
of functions $f_i:S^1\to \mathfrak{su}(2)=\mathbb R^3$ that are of the form 
$$
f_i(\theta)=a_i(\pm\cos(n_i\theta),\pm\sin(n_i \theta),0)
$$
up to permutation of the three coordinates of $\mathbb R^3$.

> Now the crucial observation is that 
>   $$
> exp(f_i):S^1\to SU(2)
> $$
>   is algebraic.

To finish the argument, pick $N\gg 1$, and consider the product 
$$
\textstyle\big(exp(\frac{f_1}N)exp(\frac{f_2}N)\ldots exp(\frac{f_n}N)\big)^N
$$
in the group.
For big $N$, that expression is an excellent approximation of $\gamma=exp(\tilde \gamma)$.

---

To deal with the case of arbitrary compact connected Lie group $G$, one can argue similarly to the way David did in his answer: the smooth loop group of $G$ contains many copies of $LSU(2)$ and $LSO(3)$ in it, and is generated by them.
The case of homogeneous spaces is then an easy consequence.

Comment: This is really nice! I'm glad I finally noticed it.